# Relation between Synchronized and Final in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, final

I want to know the relation between synchronized and final in JAVA. I have read a few articles and everybody mentions should initialise a object in the constructor using final fields otherwise un-initialised objects may cause synchronization issues between multiple threads using the same object.

For. e.g. the below code:

```
class FinalFieldExample {
  final int x;
  int y;
  static FinalFieldExample f;
  public FinalFieldExample() {
    x = 3;
    y = 4;
  }

  static void writer() {
  f = new FinalFieldExample();
  }

  static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
    int i = f.x;
    int j = f.y;
  }
 }  
}
```

The reader may read the value of x correctly but may read value of y as 0 since it is not declared final.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you think that "The reader may read the value of x correctly but may read value of y as 0 since it is nt declared final."?

Comment: Show us all your code, especially the `main()` method, that shows the behaviour you claim, thus creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Bohemian 2 threads, one calls writer and one calls reader.

Comment: @Bohemian: I am referring to this documentation :
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the final fields semantics. The [JLS #17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) gives a good summary:

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields.

In other words, provided that you don't let `this` escape during construction, you have the guarantee that all threads will see the correct value for x (i.e. 3).

Regarding the other field (y), in the absence of synchronization, no guarantee is given as to which value will be seen (the default or the constructor value).

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. Can you provide me any example for this type of constructor initialization..?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean to say that in the above code...we can get invalid entry for 'Y' because I have a static reference for the class object outside which another thread may call....?

I am not getting what exactly 'final' is doing here...I understand that final makes the object as immutable...so what if a thread calls the static reference even before the constructor is called...?Then both 'X' and 'Y' will be un-initialized. 

So my question is, How exactly we should implement the constructor for a class so that no other thread could call it untill it is properly initialized.

Comment: Thread safe publication of an object is a wider topic, but in summary, outside of immutable objects, safe publication requires some form of synchronization.

Comment: And yes a thread could see f not null but y still equal to its initial default value of 0.

Answer (score -1):

`final` fields have little to do with threading. I suspect you are thinking of `volatile` fields which do act a little like you describe.

Comment: Final fields have a specific behaviour in a multi threaded environment, similar to volatile fields.